# Making custom input method in IBUS for ubuntu 15

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ime

Is there any documentation on how to make a custom IME for a rare language that works in the latest versions of Ubuntu?

Found this, but the author states it won't work in the latest versions 
http://www.studymongolian.net/technical/how-to-create-linux-input-method-editor/

Comment: Well, as I'm trying to do the same, I must say that actually the guide works, what however doesn't is that new characters not get inserted. But I must say that the default «LaTeX» IM doesn't work for me either, so it's probably something not specific to IM.

Comment: I got it working! I had to switch in preferences of the custom IM a `Direct input` to `Table input`. But I must say, I gone from SCIM to FCITX, because of the three — IBUS, SCIM, FCITX — it seems to be the most evolved *(richer settings, a Wiki — okay, ibus also got one — and active development)*.